# from submit and print result at the same time update with url extenstion

Tags: javascript, html, forms, submit

```js
var solve = function () { 
                
             var str = document.getElementById('equ').value;

              document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML=str;
             }
```

```html
  <form onsubmit="return solve()">
<input  type="equation" id="equ" name="equation">  
<button>solve</button>
  </form>
  <p id="demo"></p>
```

I have form submit code.On the time of submit the input data print to `#demo` .but the page will be reloated. so the `#demo` data was empty. if i applied `return false` statement data will print.but not update with my url
.

> My question is print the data to html page and also update the url
>   with given input data like 'index.html?equation=mydata'.

please give ah code for satisfy the both condition.
[here is my fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/poosanth/gxydmpw0/)

`<form onsubmit="return solve()">
<input  type="equation" id="equ" name="equation"> 
<button>solve</button>  </form>
  <p id="demo"></p>`

Js

`var solve = function () { 
             var str = document.getElementById('equ').value;
              document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML=str;
           console.log(str);
             }`

Comment: First rule: add some logging `console.log(str);` and see if you are assigning something to the `demo` element.

Comment: Still, I don't understand from your post if the function `solve` is invoked at all. That is why I suggest adding some loggings.

Comment: OK OK... I ran the fiddle with console open in the browser. As soon as you click on the button you get an error that stating that `solve` is not defined. Try removing the `var` from the `solve` definition.

Comment: ya..in my localhost ..i applied `return false` into js the data was printed.but the url extension  not update with input data.remove the `return false` statement the page was refreshed and url extension  updated with input data .like 'index.html?equation=mydata'

Comment: See my solution below. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

For your condition , I seem using javascript session `localStorage` is suitable

- set your js session by `setItem(key,value)`
- get your js session by `getItem(key)`

  ```
  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML= localStorage.getItem("demo");
  var solve = function () {                
           var str = document.getElementById('equ').value;                          
            localStorage.setItem('demo',str);              
           }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working (in the fiddle) by setting the first HTML record as:

```
<form onsubmit="solve()">
```

i.e., the `return` was removed.

You still get another error I guess from the `document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML=str;', but this can be further investigated.

Comment: if you understand my question.please run with your localhost.

Comment: My friend, I updated  your fiddle and it worked (getting the entered value displayed) in spite of the additional error shown as mentioned. You can't expect me to build a project to check your code. This is what Fiddle is for.

Comment: not like that..if l applied enter input data to `123` in my url change to `index.html?equation=123`.but `#demo` is empty.i need both print and updated with url

Comment: What do you mean by URL?

Comment: Ahh!!! So you want to redirect, right? In that case, within the function you can simply set `window.href = "http://localhost/test/index.html?equation=" + str ;`